# Use Run-time Parameters in a Matlab-code S-Function

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

I have to write a Level-2 S-Function in Matlab code (C is not viable) which takes in some parameters and uses them alone and in combination.

First I tried tunable parameters, but unfortunately I haven't succeded in tuning them (the documentation doesn't tell how to `set_param` for this purpose).

Then I have bumped into [documentation of Run-Time parameters](http://it.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/run-time-parameters.html) that says

> The value of a run-time parameter that corresponds to multiple dialog
>   parameters is typically a function of the values of the dialog
>   parameters.

So I deduced that a runtime parameter would suit well, but the same documentation doesn't say how to tune and access them from a Matlab S-function, only from a C one.
Also, in [in this page](http://it.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.runtimeblock.html#f29-86355) is documented a `RuntimePrm` object that seems similar to `DialogPrm`, but trying to write the values result in an error.

Is there any way to "cache" parameter combinations without using DWorks, which would affect subsequent linearization with fake states?

Comment: Have you looked at the demo sldemo_msfcn_lms which uses run-time param from level-2 MATLAB s-function?

Comment: Yes but the changes come from outside the S-function in that simulation, not from inside.

Comment: You should be able to write to Data property of RuntimePrm object. You cannot change data type or size. They should remain as the registered type of run-time param. You also normally do not tune external dialog params from within s-function.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried it but used not to be working. Now it works.